# jQuery.val(...) does not change DOM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'll just start by presenting code that doesn't behave like it should. As it's very simple it should speak for itself.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="bla"></input>
<input id="blub"></input>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery('#bla').attr({'value': 'a'});
jQuery('input[value="a"]').val('s');

jQuery('#blub').val('d');
jQuery('input[value="d"]').val('f');
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5dww7/

**Problem:** `jQuery('input[value="d"]')` is undefined

Is this a bug? Firebug actually say that the "value" exists - so maybe a problem with the selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `val` you are changing the `value` *property*. When you use `attr` you are changing the *attribute*.

As you then use an attribute selector to select the element, it will only work if the *attribute* is present.

If you need to select elements based on the value of their `value` property you could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "whatever"; //Accesses the value property
});
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery's `.val()` method changes the value property, not the value attribute. The attribute equals selector selects by the attribute, not the property (which is done by the browser's css engine in modern browsers).